# getting the first row of two masks that meets conditions and creating a new column

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [20, 21, 333, 444, 1, 666], 'b': [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20], 'c': [222, 211, 2, 1, 100, 200]})
```

I want to use two masks. The first one finds the second row that `a` is greater than `b`. and creates column `d`. This mask is:

```
mask = (df.a >= df.b)
df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(2) & mask, 'd'] = 'x'
```

Now I want to add another mask. Basically what I want is to find the first row that has two conditions.

a) It is after the first mask (That is, it is after the second row that `a` >= `b`)

b) Column `c` is greater than column `b`

My desired output is as follows:

```
     a   b    c    d
0   20  20  222    NaN
1   21  20  211    NaN
2  333  20    2    NaN
3  444  20    1    NaN
4  1    20  100    x
5  666  20  200    NaN
```

I tried a couple of ways but the fact that it has to be after the first mask made it difficult for me.

Comment: I have not understood

Comment: Should the resulting mask satisfy `a > b` condition? Or it should be just first row after matching the first mask second time?

Comment: @GuruStron No need for a > b for the final result. You answer is fine. Thanks man :)

Comment: @GuruStron You answer does not satisfy a > b for the final result right?

Comment: @Amir yes, change `a[4]` to be less than `b[4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following monstrosity:

```py
mask2 = (mask.cumsum().eq(2) & mask) # or even just mask.cumsum().eq(2), & mask seems pointless here
df.loc[(mask2.cumsum().ge(1) & ~mask2 & (df.c >= df.b)).cumsum().eq(1), 'd'] = 'x'
```

Though probably someone smart will have a better way =)

Answer (score 0):

With single expression and [`pandas.Series.argmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmax.html):

```
df.loc[(mask.cumsum().gt(2) & (df['c'] > df['b'])).argmax(), 'd'] = 'x'
```

---

```
     a   b    c    d
0   20  20  222  NaN
1   21  20  211  NaN
2  333  20    2  NaN
3  444  20    1  NaN
4  555  20  100    x
5  666  20  200  NaN
```

Comment: `mask.cumsum().gt(2)` - OP states that the requirement is that the row should be after the first mask, but does not state that it should match it. Possibly it is wrong wording, and based on data it is not clear.